# Calling a void method

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

This should be fairly simple to answer if I have worded everything correctly.

I just need to call three methods using the "skeleton/instruction" I was given:

void addPiece(Piece piece) - Both Ship and Puck are Pieces

I have already declared my instance variables as:

```
Ship _home = new Ship(45.0, 30.0, Ship.HOME_COLOR);
Ship _away = new Ship(15.0, 30.0, Ship.AWAY_COLOR);
Puck _puck = new Puck(30.0, 30.0, Puck.COLOR);
```

I believe I did this step correctly.
How would I use these three instance variables to call the methods?

Comment: `_home.someMethod()`, `_away.someMethod()`, `_puck.someMethod()`

Comment: I am supposed to add these pieces into the "_gameEngine" by calling a method

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question clearly. But what I understand from your comment, I am assuming _gameEngine is the object that will hold these pieces. The object class of _gameEngine (like Ship is to _home) will have the addPiece method that you mention. In this method, you will need to have a data structure that will hold the pieces that you have created. For example, if you use ArrayList, then something like `hold.add(piece)` (where hold is simply the name of the declared ArrayList structure) will insert whatever is passed as piece into the structure. In your main class, you will simply need to call this method to add the piece like `_gameEngine.addPiece(_home)`.